# put and load a jquery/js in wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, themes, put

I want to use this code on my wp ,

site.
https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/v9g1x0o6/

But I don't know how put that `js` code and load that on `single.php T_T`.

This is the JS code:

```
document.getElementById("copyButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("copyTarget"), "msg");
});

document.getElementById("copyButton2").addEventListener("click",         function() {
copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("copyTarget2"), "msg");
    });

document.getElementById("pasteTarget").addEventListener("mousedown",         function() {
this.value = "";
});


function copyToClipboardMsg(elem, msgElem) {
  var succeed = copyToClipboard(elem);
var msg;
if (!succeed) {
    msg = "Copy not supported or blocked.  Press Ctrl+c to copy."
} else {
    msg = "Text copied to the clipboard."
}
if (typeof msgElem === "string") {
    msgElem = document.getElementById(msgElem);
}
msgElem.innerHTML = msg;
setTimeout(function() {
    msgElem.innerHTML = "";
}, 2000);
}

function copyToClipboard(elem) {
  // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
if (isInput) {
    // can just use the original source element for the selection and     copy
    target = elem;
    origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
    origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
} else {
    // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
    target = document.getElementById(targetId);
    if (!target) {
        var target = document.createElement("textarea");
        target.style.position = "absolute";
        target.style.left = "-9999px";
        target.style.top = "0";
        target.id = targetId;
        document.body.appendChild(target);
    }
    target.textContent = elem.textContent;
}
// select the content
var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
target.focus();
target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

// copy the selection
var succeed;
try {
      succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
} catch(e) {
    succeed = false;
}
// restore original focus
if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
    currentFocus.focus();
}

if (isInput) {
    // restore prior selection
    elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
} else {
    // clear temporary content
    target.textContent = "";
}
return succeed;
}
```

pls help me.I have new version of wordpress.
i just want to load this js code on my single.php .
This js code is a way to copy text in textarea with a button.

Comment: Go to single.php file before footer call just start  <script language="javascript">your code</script>

Comment: check screenshot http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cc61d2i28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into your single.php file before  `<?php get_footer(); ?>` this code

```
<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("copyButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("copyTarget"), "msg");
});

document.getElementById("copyButton2").addEventListener("click",         function() {
copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("copyTarget2"), "msg");
    });

document.getElementById("pasteTarget").addEventListener("mousedown",         function() {
this.value = "";
});


function copyToClipboardMsg(elem, msgElem) {
  var succeed = copyToClipboard(elem);
var msg;
if (!succeed) {
    msg = "Copy not supported or blocked.  Press Ctrl+c to copy."
} else {
    msg = "Text copied to the clipboard."
}
if (typeof msgElem === "string") {
    msgElem = document.getElementById(msgElem);
}
msgElem.innerHTML = msg;
setTimeout(function() {
    msgElem.innerHTML = "";
}, 2000);
}

function copyToClipboard(elem) {
  // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
if (isInput) {
    // can just use the original source element for the selection and     copy
    target = elem;
    origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
    origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
} else {
    // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
    target = document.getElementById(targetId);
    if (!target) {
        var target = document.createElement("textarea");
        target.style.position = "absolute";
        target.style.left = "-9999px";
        target.style.top = "0";
        target.id = targetId;
        document.body.appendChild(target);
    }
    target.textContent = elem.textContent;
}
// select the content
var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
target.focus();
target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

// copy the selection
var succeed;
try {
      succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
} catch(e) {
    succeed = false;
}
// restore original focus
if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
    currentFocus.focus();
}

if (isInput) {
    // restore prior selection
    elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
} else {
    // clear temporary content
    target.textContent = "";
}
return succeed;
}</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot , and can i use the HTML code for use the js after or before <script>?

Comment: YES why not it will work for you as i have used see screenshot  http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/0cc61d2i28